# Change '--accent-color' in Polymer though whole page under SHADY DOM

Tags: dom, polymer, styles, shady-dom

I dynamically update the '--accent-color' in all polymer elements with this:

```
Polymer.updateStyles({'--accent-color': 'red'});
```

Works fine under Shadow DOM, but in Shady DOM just some of the elements change.

Does anybody knows a way to change the custom style properties defined on

```
< style is="custom-style">
    :root {
      ...
    }
</style>
```

Comment: What's an example of an element that doesn't change? It's [working well here](http://jsbin.com/loqaqa/14/edit?html,output) with paper-button

Comment: @KevinAshcraft, I use this code  
< style is="custom-style">
--paper-button: {
   background: var(--accent-color);
  }
</style>

So you expect that the paper-button background color change, in Shadow Dom does, but not in Shady, also paper-input does not work, just to mention two, regards